# Cordova plugin to intercept HTTP(S) traffic

Tags: cordova, http, cordova-plugins

I would like to be able to intercept HTTP requests made inside a Cordova app (eg: when navigating in an iframe) and eventually modify it or amend the response from the code.

Is there any Cordova plugin that would allow that? Is this at least technically possible (Android and iOS at least)?

Comment: like when we are using inappbrowser to load a website in a iframe meanwhile you want to counter the http request Right?

Comment: @HassanALi InAppBrowser, frame or XmlHTTPrequest... any HTTP request made from inside the app actually. In some instances I would like to be able to amend the request or the response that transits.

Comment: @GyumFox This is the only plugin which i could find close to what you expect. Does not intercept request but helps you build one. - https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP

Comment: @Gandhi Interesting, but I'm not actually making the request myself (the page in the iframe does)

Comment: @GyumFox You can intercept browser HTTP/HTTPS traffic using fiddler or burp suite but inside the app i dont think you can intercept it and i dont see any plugin availability too for this. But what exactly is the need for it?

Comment: @Gandhi for example amend the response or the headers before the app gets it back.

Comment: @GyumFox I hope the best place to do it will be on the server side using filters. If you do it on client side, you are at the risk of MITM security vulnerability attack

Comment: @Gandhi yep, that's my second option

Comment: @GyumFox I believe thats the best option to avoid any request response spoofing and avoiding any vulberabilities

Comment: I have the same need because my app has to play content locally. So I need to intercept the request, check if the content is available locally, if not get it from server (and save it locally for future) and serve it.

Comment: @Arindam have you checked Web Workers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option to amend the response or the headers is to handle them on the server side rather than handling the same in client side(in mobile app) as far as i know.

**The most convincing reason for this approach is to avoid possible security vulnerabilities like MITM attacks.** It's more secured to fiddle the response in server side. Request you to rethink your approach unless you have a strong need to handle this on client side(in mobile app)

Comment: @Arindam did you found a solution? Gandhi I also need thelis on client side, I would like to remove origin from header. We can not do it on server side and try to  don't resolve it with a reverse proxy

Comment: @MichaelBurger as mentioned earlier no readymade solution available and its no advisable